# What event failed? As far as I can tell everything is mounted as expected and the system boots fine

Tags: boot, mount, swap

At boot I get a message `mountall: Event failed` but everything seems to mount fine. With verbose output I see this:

```
/ is local
/proc is virtual
/sys is virtual
/sys/fs/fuse/connections is virtual
/sys/kernel/debug is virtual
/sys/kernel/security is virtual
/dev is virtual
/dev/pts is virtual
/run is virtual
/run/lock is virtual
/run/shm is virtual
/dev/xvda2 is swap
/tmp/sessions is virtual
mounting event sent for swap /dev/xvda2
mounted event handled for /
mount / [1355] exited normally
mount /proc [1358] exited normally
mount /sys [1365] exited normally
mount /sys/fs/fuse/connections [1371] exited normally
mount /sys/kernel/debug [1375] exited normally
mount /sys/kernel/security [1378] exited normally
mount /dev [1381] exited normally
mount /dev/pts [1385] exited normally
mount /run [1387] exited normally
mount /run/lock [1388] exited normally
mount /run/shm [1389] exited normally
mount /tmp/sessions [1390] exited normally
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 0/11 swap 0/1
mounted event handled for /sys
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 1/11 swap 0/1
mounted event handled for /sys/fs/fuse/connections
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 2/11 swap 0/1
mounted event handled for /sys/kernel/security
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 3/11 swap 0/1
mounted event handled for /proc
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 4/11 swap 0/1
mounted event handled for /dev/pts
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 5/11 swap 0/1
mounted event handled for /run/lock
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 6/11 swap 0/1
mounted event handled for /run/shm
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 7/11 swap 0/1
mounted event handled for /tmp/sessions
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 8/11 swap 0/1
mounted event handled for /sys/kernel/debug
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 9/11 swap 0/1
mounted event handled for /dev
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 10/11 swap 0/1
mounting event handled for swap /dev/xvda2
activating /dev/xvda2
swapon /dev/xvda2 [1391] exited normally
mountall: Event failed
mounted event handled for /run
virtual finished
local finished
remote finished
All filesystems mounted
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 11/11 swap 0/1
mounted event handled for swap /dev/xvda2
swap finished
local 1/1 remote 0/0 virtual 11/11 swap 1/1
```

How can I find out what failed exactly?

---

Output of `mount -a`

```
mount: sys already mounted or /sys busy
mount: according to mtab, sysfs is already mounted on /sys
mount: none already mounted or /dev/pts busy
mount: according to mtab, devpts is already mounted on /dev/pts
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with /var/log/boot.log and /var/log/dmesg.

Comment: The `mountall: Event failed` is the only thing I can find in the logs.

Comment: If you look at /etc/fstab is there an entry for a device no longer connected to the machine such as an external drive or USB flash drive?

Comment: Not [that I can see](http://pastebin.com/B0yWnNfs).

Comment: What does sudo mount -a return? I think that would mount any fstab entries. It might give us a clue on the issue...

Comment: I've added the output for `mount -a` at the end of the question.